# "branch is up-to-date with origin" but actually not

Tags: git

Is the message a bit mis-leading?

When checkout a branch (eg., `b535`), git does it and says **"Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/b535'."** That sounds like what I have in my local branch `b535` is up-to-date.

```
$ git checkout b535
Previous HEAD position was 8aa0145... master - resyns
Switched to branch 'b535'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/b535'.
```

**But actually it's not**. When doing a `git pull`, it found updates from remote and updating local branch.

```
$ git pull origin b535
remote: Counting objects: 39, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (39/39), done.
remote: Total 39 (delta 31), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (39/39), done.
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, your branch is up to date with the last *known* position of origin/b535. If you want `git status` to give you more accurate info without having to do a `git pull`, do a `git fetch` instead. This will update origin/b535, without changing your local b535.

Comment: Yeah thanks -  so the message could probably: "Your branch is up-to-date with last-known 'origin/b535'." It'd give novice users more warning I suppose.. But yes you help make it clear.

Comment: `origin/b535` is the name of the tracking branch, which is what it's up-to-date with respect to. Confusing, perhaps, but accurate. :-P

Comment: @artm: May be 'with local copy of' instead of 'last-known'

Answer (score 3):

This is because Git can only know about what it has downloaded. Your local copy of `origin/b535` may or may not be up-to-date with your `origin` remote.

You need to manually `git fetch` to ensure your origin branches are in sync with your Git server...Git won't do that for you automatically with the `status` command.

For an up-to-date status command you could define an alias like this:

```
[alias]
    rstatus = "!git fetch && git status"
```