# Git is outputting `Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.` when trying to commit, but changes are being made

Tags: git, macos, github

So I set up a new computer recently (Mac M1), downloaded / setup vscode and am now having trouble with a repo I'm working on.

My goal is just to be able to push to the repository on github when changes are made. However I've been running into a problem where when I try to commit, my terminal outputs that my branch is up to date.

I first realized the problem when I tried to committing a change in the code to the github repo (first running `git add .` and then running `git commit -m "..."` . While it had worked previously (such as when initializing the repository), this time there was a message:

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

The changes however were not on the github repository.

What did I try:

[One post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37270273/20962819) mentioned it might be that my "local branch doesn't know about the remote branch" and to run `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master` (or in my case `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/main`). After running that, the output was `branch 'main' set up to track 'origin/main'.` but when I tried to run `git commit -m "..."` again I still got the same output as before about my branch being up to date (despite this not being the case).

[Another post](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23135#discussioncomment-3239287) suggested to try to make a new repo and push the existing code. I tried a few variations of this

1. Running `m -rf .git/` and then initializing the repo in the same folder but pushing to the same 2. Deleting the folder and cloning a new one from github and then making a new commit
2. Initializing a new github repo and pushing the code.
   While the first commit worked for each of these ways, following commits returned the same output as the initial problem.

[This article](https://careerkarma.com/blog/git-nothing-to-commit-working-directory-clean/) suggested to run `git remote add origin https://github.com/.../...` but resulted in the same output for me after running and trying to commit the changes.

[Another article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187030/branch-is-up-to-date-with-origin-but-actually-not) suggested my "local copy... may or may not be up-to-date with your origin remote" and to run `git fetch` but after running `git status` again, it outputted that everything was up to date.

Most other articles and posts were some variation of these and the ones that weren't I tried my best to follow but didn't see any changes.

What was I expecting:

I was expecting for there to be changes to commit and that when I pushed, the github repository would reflect those changes.

Comment: I suggest you always run `git status` or `git status -uno` before `git commit`, to check which files are to be committed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of `git status`, double-check the output of:

```
git remote -v
git branch -avv
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all --branches
```

The last one should show you:

- where is your local HEAD
- where is origin/main

You will see what has not yet been pushed, if if those commits are associated to a branhc (or if you are in a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309) mode)

Comment: `git remote -v` outputs:
`origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)`
`origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)`


`git branch -avv` outputs:

`* main                6b8d505 [origin/main] testing git again`
  `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main`
  `remotes/origin/main 6b8d505 testing git again`

`git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all --branches` outputs:
`* 6b8d505 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD) testing git again`
`* 4b13fd5 trying to fix git issues`

Comment: @asker430`HEAD -> main` is at main: everything has been pushed

Comment: while it might look like that, even if I make a change and try to commit, it outputs that there is nothing to commit and the github repo doesn't update

Comment: @asker430 committing alone is not enough and remain in your local repository. You need `git push` to publish it.

Comment: Yeah I've run `git push`, `git push origin main` and other variations. I think it might be a problem with github signin or authentication.  I signed out and back in and the first commit and push worked but the following ones didn't (this was also the case for initting branches - the init and first commit and push worked but following ones didn't)

Comment: @asker430 What do you get on a `git push`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very silly.

I had just downloaded vscode to my new computer and never turned autosave on. Because of this, git wasn't aware of the changes I was making and so it outputted that my branch was up to date (when the text editor seemed to show otherwise).